# How can I control which device gets downloaded apps on the Google Play website?

Tags: google-play-store

I have two devices, a Note 2 and a Nook HD Plus. I can download apps to each device with their Google Play apps with no problem. but I don't know how to choose which device gets the app download on the Google Play website.

Answer (score 8):

When you click the "Install" button on the app on the Play Store website, you should be prompted which device you want to use.

[image: screen shot showing my two devices]

If you're not seeing that, then I suspect you're using different Google accounts on your devices.

Comment: Beaten to the punch by Al :)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are using the same Google account on both devices to purchase and install apps from, it should prompt you for the device to install when you click the "Install" button on the Google Play Store website:
[image: Store]

You can even customize the names of your devices. On the main Google Play Store [website](https://play.google.com/store) look for the "gear" icon on the top-right corner of the screen:
[image: Settings]

Click it and select the `Settings` option, which will bring you to the Devices page:
[image: Devices]

Here you can click the `Edit` button, enter the name you wish and click `Update`.  Now the Install prompt will use the names you've given your devices.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I was trying to add an app to my new tablet that was already installed on my phone. The button said "installed", but when I clicked it asked for a device.